# Android reports lifecycle is STARTED when checking in onResume

Tags: android, lifecycle

In my main activity:

```kotlin
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    Log.d("onResume, lifecycle: ${lifecycle.currentState}")
}
```

I expect:

`onResume, lifecycle: RESUMED`

To my shock and dismay, Android reports:

`onResume, lifecycle: STARTED`

In what world is this not either a lie or a bug in the SDK?  How can the activity be in `STARTED` state INSIDE the callback for `onResume()`?

Whatever the answer, I'm going to have a problem with it. If I can't use `lifecycle` to actually check the lifecycle, then how can I check the lifecycle?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't [adding an observer](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lc) if you want to know when the `Lifecycle` changes?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I didn't even know it was a thing. Never had a use until possibly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.  Your app isn't resumed yet.  It's in the process of being resumed.  The state won't change until onResume and associated code in the framework is finished.

Why do you need to check the state anyway?  It's usually sufficient to react to changes in state.  Any code that depends on checking the state would be a code smell.

Comment: Incorrect: When the activity enters the resumed state, it comes to the foreground, and THEN the system invokes the `onResume()` callback.  By the time `onResume` is called, the activity IS resumed. Why I'm checking state is irrelevant.

Comment: @rmirabelle The fact its in the foreground doesn't mean the state is resumed.  It means that it's *BEING* resumed.  The state isn't actually changed until after the call to onResume.  Look at the AOSP code, it's right there.  That's why your code is returning STARTED instead.

Comment: My comment is from the documentation for `onResume()`. It clearly states "the activity enters the resumed state". Then I verify the state as `STARTED`. So no, the activity hasn't entered the resumed state at all. Once the activity enters a state, that is its state. Otherwise, it hasn't entered that state. Is the documentation wrong? Or is there no parity between lifecycle states and lifecycle events?

Comment: @rmirabelle No, you're just no understanding a basic concept here.  onResume is NOT called from the resumed state.  It's called during the transition.  The state variable isn't transitioned to RESUMED until after the onResume function returns.  Basically, the framework calls onResume then sets the state.  This is fairly common implementation for a statemachine.  The app isn't in the RESUMED state until all the work in onResume is done, because if ti changes the state first something may not yet have been intitialized and break your app.  You just don't understand the pattern being used.

Comment: I appreciate your input. So the docs for `onResume`:  "When the activity enters the resumed STATE...THEN invokes onResume" are clearly outdated,  You, and the docs for `Lifecycle` are correct.  You rightly mention code smell.  In my case it was. But it smelled like apple pie as presented by google.